# How to clear memory after boot screen in Android

Tags: java, android

I've a boot screen structured in this way:

```
public class BootActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_boot);

        Thread welcomeThread = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    super.run();
                        sleep(2000);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                } finally {
                    Intent i = new Intent(BootActivity.this,
                            Main_activity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        welcomeThread.start();
    }
}
```

I've added into layout *R.layout.activity_boot* an HD background image. I'll use this screen to load some things to use after in my main activity. I've read that activity goes in background and it's paused when another activity is opened and continue to occupy memory space. I've performed App memory monitoring and found that I've about 50Mb of memory used when BootActivity is opened. Since this activity will never be opened again, how should I clear memory to have more memory space for next Activity?

Answer (score 0):

Add `System.exit(0);` after `finish();`

```
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    super.run();
                        sleep(2000);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                } finally {
                    Intent i = new Intent(BootActivity.this,
                            Main_activity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                    System.exit(0);


    }
```

it may clear some memory

Also you can use `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)` with intent it will remove activity from back stack

```
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```